# What does it mean to scanf("%d", array[i] + 1)? Why is the +1 there?

Tags: c++, arrays

I've seen a lot of code snippets that start the for loop from 1 not 0 and scanf into the `arr[i] + 1` address, what does it mean?

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) { scanf("%d", arr[i]+1); }
```

`arr` is a two dimensional array:

```
int arr[500][500];
```

Comment: Whats the declaration of `arr`?

Comment: Please post the full code...

Comment: a two dimensional array, arr[500][500], sorry for not including.

Comment: Then `arr[i]+1` is equivalent to `&arr[i][1]`.

Comment: The author is not comfortable with using natural 0-based array indexes, and stubbornly insists on using 1-based indexes everywhere. Do not use it as a learning example. Ignore it. Forget it. Otherwise you're setting yourself up for a lot of grief.

Comment: "what does it mean?"  It means that person should not be programming in C++.

Comment: Presumably, the value of `n` is no more than 499 (and, in particular, not 500), because any larger value would result in indexing out of bounds. Which is part of the reason that using 1-based indices is a really bad idea.

Comment: One-based indexing means the code should subtract 1 from the index, not add one, so apart from looking horrible, it looks suspicious as well. To keep your sanity, if you _really_ want to use one-based indexing, just have an unused element at index zero. Bit of waste, but keeps your life sane.

Comment: @gnasher729: this is exactly what this code does. 0th element unused.

Answer (score 3):

> ...what does it mean?

It means that "Old habits die hard".

It means that the author of that code probably was an experienced programmer in a programming language where the default base index of an array is 1. The most likely candidates are ALGOL, AWK, COBOL, Fortran and Smalltalk. They not want to change their old habits and adopt the indexing of C++.

The other languages which have the default base index of an array as 1 are XPath/XQuery, Wolfram Language, Sass, R, PL/I, MATLAB, Mathematica, Lua, Lingo, Julia, FoxPro, CFML, APL.

Note: The above information was gleaned from wiki's article on [Comparison of programming languages (array).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_(array)#Indexing)